# Static List View with custom rows

Tags: react-native

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere so I had to resort to ask here...

Is it possible to use a List View but instead:

```
<ListView>
  <Row>
    <Text> Row 1 </Text>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Text> Row 2 </Text>
  </Row>
</ListView>
```

Basically lay it out statically instead of using a render row, Especially if each row is going to have a much different layout. Using a render row function kinda makes it a pain to not have all identical layouts

Comment: here is a solution with ListView: https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-how-to-use-the-listview-component-a0ec44cf1fe8